# create RAW folder under RES folder in android studio and are not showing up in the file view

Tags: directory, raw

Yes, I do see some other similar questions to this, but not the same problem.  I am trying to create another layout folder (layout-sw720dp).  I have tried to Right click on res folder>New folder> Raw Resources Folder.  This does create the required folder-unless I am misunderstanding, underneath the navigation bar at the top there is 'project name'>app>src>main>res.  If I click on that, it shows the folder that was newly created, but the folder does not show in project view under the 'res' folder.  By clicking on my created folder in the above that I mentioned, it does nothing, nor have any sort of indication that I am working from "layout-sw720dp" folder.

In all the videos I see, its as simple as what I stated and the folder is visible in project view, but in my case it is not there.

*See image for context[image]